# dynamoDb load not working with table having both hash key and range key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table which has both hashkey and range key. The table is currently empty and I am trying to get the value from the table using load() passing hashkey as the argument, but it is returning nothing. Neither I am getting NULL nor any exception. Just nothing is happening.

But if I use query() and using query expression atleast I am getting the list and its size is 0, which is expected.

I'm not able to wrap my head around the first scenario. What is happening wrongly? Is it like we cannot use load(hashkey) if the table has both hash key and range key or I am missing out something important ?

Answer (score 0):

You would get error if there is an item I suppose. `Load` is looking for a specific item exactly matching your primary key but `hash+range` key is your composite primary key not only your `hash` key. So you cannot simply ask an item giving only a `hash` key when you have composite primary keys. There might be multiple values on that `hash` but you are trying to `load` which is aiming for the single item. All you can do is to `query` because then you have retrieve multiple items

```
|  HashKey  |  RangeKey | 
|:---------:|----------:|
| SomeHash1 |  Range1   |
| SomeHash1 |  Range2   |
| SomeHash1 |  Range3   |
| SomeHash2 |  Range1   |
```

Image you wanna `load` SomeHash1. There are 3 items but `load` is for retrieving an item with a primary key.

Comment: so is it like if my table has both hash key and range key, by default i will have composite PK (Hash+ Range) ? and in that case I will have to use `query` ? the scenario that you explained using someHash1 is pretty close to what will happen in my case. And in the DDB query expression do i need to set the hashkey value `queryExpression.setHashKeyValues`

Comment: Hash+Range is the definition of composite primary key. No idea what you mean by `queryExpression.setHashKeyValues`. I dont know the language you are using. But, yes you have to query everytime if you are only using hashkey. Load can only work with HashKey and RangeKey given.

Comment: i think in the last line you misplaced query and Load. Can you please confirm ?

Comment: No it was correct. `Load` requires a primary key as a parameter. In your case your primary key is composite. Hash Key and Range Key. So you have to do like `Load(hashkey, rangekey)`. `Query` requires only a index which is your HashKey. So you can do like `Query(hashkey)`. If you didnt have range key in your table you would be able to `Load(hashkey)` but this time `Query(hashkey)` wouldnt do any good.